# Chef-12 Validation Public Key Stopped Working

Tags: chef-infra

I have the old way of bootstrapping the chef node. It uses validation.pem for the initial connection before it creates client.pem for future connections.
This was working as expected, but all of a sudden public key of the validator stopped working. What could be the reason for it if anyone else has faced this issue?